# Drop 0 values, NaN values, and empty strings

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd   
import csv 
import numpy as np

readfile = pd.read_csv('50.csv')
filevalues= readfile.loc[readfile['Customer'].str.contains('Lam Dep', na=False), 'Jul-18\nQty']
filevalues = filevalues.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True) 
filevalues = filevalues.fillna(int(0))
int_series = filevalues.astype(int) 
calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: x*(1/1.2))


print(calculated_series)
```

So I have hundreds of csv files with many empty spots for values. Some of the blanks spaces are detected as NaNs and others are empty strings.This has Forced me to create my code in the way it is right now, and the reason so is that I need to conduct a formula on each value so I changed all such NaNs and empty strings to 0 so that I am able to conduct any formula ( in this example 1/1.2.) The problem is that I do not want to see values that are 0, NaN or empty strings when printing my dataframe.

I have tried to use the following:

```
filevalues = filevalues.dropna()
```

But because certain csv files have empty strings, this method does not fully work and get the error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '    '
```

I have also tried the following after converting all values to 0:

```
filevalues = filevalues.loc[:, (filevalues != 0).all(axis=0)]
```

and

```
mask = np.any(np.isnan(filevalues) | np.equal(a, 0), axis=1)
```

Every method seems to be giving different errors. Is there a clean way to not count these types of values when I am printing my pandas dataframe? Please let me know if an example csv file is needed.

Comment: What do you mean by `"I dont want to see values that are 0` ? You realize that `.dropna()` will remove all rows that have at least one `NaN` cell right?

Comment: @RafaelC Yes but some of the cell values are empty strings so I am unable to just do dropna() right? Because I tried that code before for certain files and I would get an error

Comment: you can always do `.replace("", np.nan)` or `map({'':np.nan, 0: np.nan})` and *then* `.dropna()`

Comment: @RafaelC I just tried that and got the same error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '    '

Comment: Seems like you dont have an empty string, but strings filled with whitespaces. Do for your string column `df['col'] = df.col.str.strip()` and then try the above methods

Comment: @RafaelC Would you be able to explain this the code you just commented? I am not sure exactly how to integrate it within my code.

Comment: You would get your string columns and apply `.strip()` to their values. `strip` will strip out all whitespaces and `tabs` your cells might have, such that `'     '` would become `''` (i.e. an actual empty string). *Then*, when it is done, `.replace('',np.nan)` would replace all these values to nan

Comment: Okay That makes sense however I changed my code to this:

readfile = pd.read_csv('51.csv')
filevalues= readfile.loc[readfile['Customer'].str.contains('Lam Dep', na=False), 'Jul-18\nQty']
filevalues['Jul-18\nQty'] = filevalues.col.str.strip()
int_series = filevalues.astype(int) 
calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: x*(1/1.2))

Comment: and getting the error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'col'

@RafaelC My apologies, I did not know how else to show you how I am running my code

Comment: substitue `col` by your column name. For example, if your column is called `year`, do `df.year`. Or `df['year'].str.strip...`

Comment: I wrote in like this: filedateval = filevalues['Jul-18\nQty'].str.strip()

Comment: @RafaelC And get the error: KeyError: 'Jul-18\nQty'

Comment: @HarisKhaliq put it after the `readfile = ` line and make it `readfile['Jul-18\nQty'] = ['Jul-18\nQty'].str.strip()`

Answer (score 2):

Got it to work! Here is the answer if it is of use to anyone.

```
import pandas as pd   
import csv 
import numpy as np

readfile = pd.read_csv('50.csv')
filevalues= readfile.loc[readfile['Customer'].str.contains('Lam Dep', na=False), 'Jul-18\nQty']

filevalues = filevalues.replace(" ", "", regex=True)
filevalues.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True) # replace empty string with np.nan
filevalues.dropna(inplace=True) # drop nan values
int_series = filevalues.astype(int) # change type

calculated_series = int_series.apply(lambda x: x*(1/1.2))

print(calculated_series)
```